# How to remove duplicates in two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this one :

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"X1":["a","b","c"], "X2":["b","c","d"], "X3":[500,200,10]})
```

I want to keep only the first and the third rows.

Expected output :

```
        X1  X2  X3
    0   a   b   500
    2   c   d   10
```

(X1,X2)=(b,c) is a duplicate of (a,b) for me because X1=X2.

(c,d) is also a duplicate of (b,c) but (b,c) will be removed first.

How can I do that in general?

Comment: Can you add the expected output for this example?

Answer (score 0):

This is your data...

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"X1":["a","b","c"], "X2":["b","c","d"], "X3":[500,200,10]})

  X1 X2   X3
0  a  b  500
1  b  c  200
2  c  d   10
```

If I understood correctly: `(a,b) = (b,c) = (c=d)` therefore `a=b=c` and `b=c=d`. 
If you replace your data X1 and X2, your data would be:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"X1": ["a", "a", "a"], "X2": ["b", "b", "b"], "X3": [500, 200, 10]})

# Keep first duplicate
df_first = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['X1', 'X2'], keep='first')

# Keep last duplicate
df_last = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['X1', 'X2'], keep='last')

# Concatenate DataFrames
df_clean = pd.concat([df_first, df_last], axis=0)
```

... or you can do it in one line

```py
df_clean = pd.concat([df.drop_duplicates(subset=['X1', 'X2'], keep='first'), df.drop_duplicates(subset=['X1', 'X2'], keep='last')], axis=0)
```

**Output:**

```py
print(df_clean)

  X1 X2   X3
0  a  a  500
2  a  a   10
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: No, the result of your code is different from the output I want to get

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is the exact output that you want?